# Windows Web Chat Application

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, web, chat

I have a task to develop chat application with .net that has 2 interfaces for chat . first chat interface from windows and other chat interface from web application .
I'm interested in wcf service . and found many samples that make windows chat application or web chat application but i don't know how to mix the 2 interfaces in one application .
how to connect the chat server from 2 platform ??

Comment: WCF is the wrong component for real time communications. Its a classic example of how to use SignalR.

Comment: Check out SignalR at http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 0):

wcf samples showing chat applications are great, but they aren't suited for real life scenarios as I understand it.  [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) is designed exactly for that and would be worth investigating.